# Nginx reverse proxying for regions

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

Can we use nginx reverse proxy features to delegate the request per region basis:
e.g.

```
Client Request(EUROPE)->NGINX(http://my.app.com)->HOST(EUROPE)
Client Request(APAC)->NGINX(http://my.app.com)->HOST(APAC)
```

If someone can guide me or provide some meaningful example it would be fo great help.

Best

Answer (score 1):

Check the nginx geoip module.

What you can do is create upstreams for target regions (Europe, Asia, etc), and map specific country codes, or better yet, continents (EU, NA, etc) to these upstreams.

Something like this:

```
map $geoip_city_continent_code $upstream {
    EU      eu_backend;
    NA      na_backend;
}

...

upstream eu_backend {
    zone zone_eu 128k;
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy;
}

upstream na_backend {
    zone zone_na 128k;
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy;
}
...
```

`